# get info from sql table then update it

Tags: mysql, node.js

Im new to mysql so bare with me. So I have a node js login system. What I'm trying to achieve is once the users' login information is verified, right before redirecting to the home page I want to update the users' login count in my SQL table. The method I'm trying to use now is not right probably because of my SQL update syntax. How can I first get the previously logged login count for that user then Increment 1 to it then update the user login count? Currently, I get error `` ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax;  check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO users SET `userLoginCount` = 2' at line 1 `` Thanks in advance.

```js
const login = async(req, res) => {
  const {
    username,
    password
  } = req.body;
  if (!username || !password) return res.json({
    status: 'error',
    error: 'Please enter your username and password'
  })
  else {
    db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?', [username], async(Err, result) => {
      if (Err) throw Err;
      if (!result.length || !await bcrypt.compare(password, result[0].password)) return res.json({
        status: 'error',
        error: 'Incorrect Username or password'
      })
      else {
        const token = jwt.sign({
          id: result[0].id
        }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
          expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES
        })
        const cookieOption = {
          expiresIn: new Date(Date.now() + process.env.COOKIE_EXPIRES * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
          httpOnly: true
        }
        res.cookie('userRegistered', token, cookieOption)
        //I wanna get the previous login count for the logged in user then Increment 1 to it then update it before user is redirected to home page.
        db.query('UPDATE INTO users SET ?', {
          userLoginCount: result[0].userLoginCount + 1
        }, (error, results) => {
          if (error) throw error;
          console.log(results)
        })
        console.log('user ' + username + ' logged in')
        return res.json({
          status: 'success',
          success: 'User has been logged In'
        })
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not setting the syntax properly I had to update the specific users' table row using their username and then increment 1 to their previous login count. Code below works fine.

```js
const login = async(req, res) => {
  const {
    username,
    password
  } = req.body;
  if (!username || !password) return res.json({
    status: 'error',
    error: 'Please enter your username and password'
  })
  else {
    db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?', [username], async(Err, result) => {
      if (Err) throw Err;
      if (!result.length || !await bcrypt.compare(password, result[0].password)) return res.json({
        status: 'error',
        error: 'Incorrect Username or password'
      })
      else {
        const token = jwt.sign({
          id: result[0].id
        }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
          expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES
        })
        const cookieOption = {
          expiresIn: new Date(Date.now() + process.env.COOKIE_EXPIRES * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
          httpOnly: true
        }
        res.cookie('userRegistered', token, cookieOption)
        db.query('UPDATE users SET userLoginCount = ? WHERE username = ?', [result[0].userLoginCount + 1, result[0].username], (error, results) => {
          if (error) throw error;
        })
        console.log('user ' + username + ' logged in')
        return res.json({
          status: 'success',
          success: 'User has been logged In'
        })
      }
    })
  }
}
```